# Font Color in HTML Email - Gmail

Tags: css, gmail, html-email

I know that I have to use inline CSS to style anything in an HTML email, but I am noticing an odd override that is occuring in gmail. I am trying to change the color of the text in a table row:

```
<tr style='color: #000; font-size: 14px; font-family: Verdana, serif;'>
```

but when I open this email in gmail, the font-family and black color is being overwrote by gmail stylings. I'm seeing this via Firebug:

[image]

That purple color is being used instead of the black I want, and the font family is defaulting to arial,sans-serif. Does anyone know of a way to safely override the styling that gmail is forcing on me?

**UPDATE**

I changed the color to a non-black color, i.e. #212a2c and the color changed correctly, but the font-family is still stuck on arial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you are styling the TR but gmail is over riding it with a style to the TD. When a TD and a TR conflict, the TD will win because it is the most immediate container...the closest match as per css3 rules.  I think if you use inline style on your TD you will be able to over ride it.

Comment: Yea I just figured that. Added styling at the `<td>` level and it works now. This will get tedious.... Thanks.

Comment: Still strange that simply changing the color from black to something else was enough to override the purple...

Comment: I can't find anyting 'official' about this, but from experience I have noticed odd behavior when mixing 3-letter color codes with 6-letter color codes, even though they should be equivalent.  In your case, #000 did not work in your original example, but I would be most interested to know if #000000 would work.

Comment: #000000 doesn't work; #111 does though - it appears gmail has an odd allergy to pure black.

Answer (score 5):

GMail will change your links from black (#000000) to the default blue, presumably as an anti-spamming feature.

To get around this, just change the color of the font to (#000001), e.g.

```
<a href="#" style="color: #000001;">Click HERE</a>
```

Comment: This is no longer the case. #000000 will work as intended, tested it right now.

Answer (score 4):

From experience I have found the safest thing to do with color codes is always to use the 6 number code - I had a similar problem once and it was fixed simply by changing the color code from 3 digits to 6 - it doesn't take any time at all to type 3 extra numbers after all :)

Answer (score 4):

1. Dont use styles on `<tr>`, do it on `<td>` or a `<span>` around the text.
2. It dosnt matter if you write #000, #000000 or Black as a color :)

Comment: Wow, using `<span>` [stuff] `</span>` worked like a charm for my html emails! I was bamboozled prior to stumbling across this.

Comment: Glad I could help you with my 7 years old post ;)

Answer (score 3):

*"It dosnt matter if you write #000, #000000 or Black as a color :)"*

Yes it does, sometimes emails render 3 hexadecimal colours in a slightly different way. As a rule of thumb, it's best to stick with 6 for compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same issue and I got a workaround to this by trying to give text a gradient but keep both colour same. It worked for me.

```css
.gradient-text {
        background-image: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        background-clip: text;
        color: transparent;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }
```

Also, remember some email service providers like Gmail do cut of the head of your template and mentioned here [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667641/css-not-working-while-sending-html-email-via-intent-in-android) so I tried putting  style tag inside the body tags and it worked