# CSS not working while Sending HTML email via Intent in android

Tags: android, html, css, android-intent, gmail

I want to send Html via mail app, problem is with CSS is not working when I am using Gmail to compose/send mail

And here is the intent spinet

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Summary");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<div style='background: red;'>TEST</div>"));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT,  "<div style='background: red;'>TEST</div>");
intent.setType("text/html");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"));
```

Even I applied inline CSS its not working, Can Any help what's wrong am I doing

Answer (score 2):

Gmail cuts off the head, so the CSS gets lost. For HTML Emails, you should always use inline styles.

*Edit:*
The general rule to use inline styles is still true, but in your specific case, it seems to be an issue with sending a HTML Mail with an Intent. I found in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13646697/3775858) on SO, that this may isn't possible.

Comment: Okay But even I applied inline CSS, why its not applying, you can check body,paragraph tags in above html

Comment: Try to inspect the email with F12 in your browser and check, if the inline CSS is present. I sent an test HTML mail to my account which works fine with inline CSS.

Comment: can you send demo html template

Comment: it was just `<div style="background: red;">TEST</div>`. Do you sed the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tag with your Mail? If so, try to get rid of this markup, since it is not neccessary at all.

Comment: I had no succes with above line, I got error when I inspect browser `Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'nonce-rSJ9f0mebhmozadRI4El0gv9N6Y' 'strict-dynamic' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: 'report-sample'". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.`

Comment: Ok, sounds like you also have some inline Javscript, which gets blocked due to security reasons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156454/discussion-between-san-and-matthias-s).